# Syntax error: Concatenate - Derived Column - 2 column + a constant string

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I am brand new to SSIS and SQL Server.  I am doing lots of read on the web and looking at a book or 2 to purchase.

In the process I am trying to accomplish a new column with a constant string plus some dashes and 2 columns.
 But I am not getting it even close.  I can get the 2 columns with No dash and No text but that does not accomplish the goal.
 I have read the TechNet and Microsoft SSIS Pages as well as searched/read here but still I am struggling.
Can someone help me with the syntax ?   Thank you in advanced for your assistance.

Desired goal is something like:

Result:  DtMMP-202-PA-A97-1

Environment:

The New Column would be like the following (not proper syntax):
 MMID column is an     integer
 PymtAuth column is   nvarchar100

```
"DtMMP-" +  [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]
```

Desired Result:  DtMMP-202-PA-A97-1

Even if I remove the front end string and just combine the 2 columns I am unsuccessful.

```
 [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]
```

I even got separate and tried 2 integer fields…

```
 [MMID] + '-' + [RegID]
```

If I leave out the  '-' it seems to accept it but the Dashed are needed.

The Objective is:

```
 "DtMMP-" +  [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]
```

Result:  DtMMP-202-PA-A97-1

Thank you again.

---

"DtMMP-" +  [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]
Creates error

Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: Attempt to set the result type of binary operation ""DtMMP-" + MMID" failed with error code 0xC0047080.

Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: Computing the expression ""DtMMP-" + [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]" failed with error code 0xC0047084. The expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.

Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: The expression ""DtMMP-" + [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 2]" is not valid.

Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[Derived Column 2]".

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Comment: do you get any error? if so, you need to cast  [MMID] to character when concatenating with numbers

Comment: BTW, please mention what is your database engine. sq-server is MicrosoftSQL Server and is different than mysql

Comment: Flicker thank you for your response...  Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and yes when using

 "DtMMP-" +  [MMID] + "-PA-"  + [PymtAuth]

the error I am getting is as follows which in principle I understand is mixing data types but I am unclear on how to overcome the problem.

If cast is my answer then I will go do some more research on  cast

Comment: I added the error message to the Question above.

Comment: The reason is you are adding number to string. You need to conver MMID to string use conversion function. If cast can help you, you need to say CAST(MMID as varchar)

Comment: I have tried a few variations of  CAST(MMID as varchar)... and have searched - still struggling-Again I am using Derived Column,  Receiving Error:  Error at Create Opportunity from MM Library [Derived Column [391]]: Attempt to parse the expression "CAST(MMID as varchar)" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

Comment: What version of SQL server

Comment: Cast(MMID as varchar (4000))  does this error out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"DtMMP-" + (DT_WSTR,4)MMID + "-PA-" + PymtAuth
```

You have to convert MMID to DT_WSTR

Comment: 2 things. 1st - this did the trick!!  2nd thank you for being so specific on how it should look.  the full syntax.

Comment: I also got some additional guidance to place the whole thing in a string - what are your thoughts??
  
 (DT_STR,50,1252) ("DtMMP-" + (DT_WSTR,50)MMID +"-PA-" +  [PymtAuth])

Comment: MOSTLY ... Thank YOU!